# How to get if the file is type of JPEG with jpeglib.h

Tags: c++, jpeg, libpng

I would like to ask you if there is any way how to get information(bool value) if the file is jpeg.

I solved it in png like this:

```
bool isPng = !png_sig_cmp(reinterpret_cast<png_const_bytep>(header), 0, number);
```

I tried to search on the internet and read the documentation of `jpeglib`, but didn't solve it.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the first few bytes of the file you should see the JFIF characters in a jpeg. Using `jpeglib` you can attempt to read the header data and fail on that.